# How to change bar color and legends in ColumnChart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, column-chart

I am using [Google Chart](https://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/latest/examples/column/) to display [Column Chart](https://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/latest/examples/column/) for 2 things :

1) Success

2) Failed

> For Success : Color = Green
>
> For Failed  : Color = Red

But problem is ColumnChart always **display bar in blue color** and also i want legends as :

```
Success
Failed
```

But it displays `Legends` as "values" as shown below :[image]

Code :

```js
 angular.module("google-chart-sample", ["googlechart"])
.controller("GenericChartCtrl", function ($scope) {
    var data = { "data": { "graphResponse": { "cols": [{ "label": "Types", "type": "string" }, { "label": "values", "type": "number" }], "rows": [{ "c": [{ "v": "success" }, { "v": 11 }] }, { "c": [{ "v": "failed" }, { "v": 0 }] }] } } };
    $scope.myChartObject = {};
    $scope.myChartObject.type = "ColumnChart";
    $scope.myChartObject.data = data.data.graphResponse;
    $scope.myChartObject.options = {
        slices: {
            0: { color: '#50ce68' },
            1: { color: '#ff7b7b' },
        },
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.18/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-chart/1.0.0-beta.1/ng-google-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.4/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<ul ng-app="google-chart-sample" ng-controller="GenericChartCtrl">
    <div google-chart chart="myChartObject" style="height:600px; width:100%;"></div>
    </ul>
```

**I want Success bar as Green and Failed as Red and i also want 2 Legends(Success -Green and Failed-Red)**

I will appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 4):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using role and give color green for success and red for failed

**{"role": "style", "type": "string"}**

```
  var data = { "data": 
                { "graphResponse": 
                 { "cols": [{ "label": "Types", "type": "string" }, 
                            { "label": "values", "type": "number" },
                            {"role": "style", "type": "string"}], 
                  "rows": [{ "c": [{ "v": "success" }, { "v": 11 },{"v":"green"}] }, 
                           { "c": [{ "v": "failed" }, { "v": 0 },{"v":"red"}] }] 
                 } } };
```

Issue with legend is that it takes the label:"values" as legend by default and one way to customize is to make legend:none and customize with below code

**HTML:**

```
<div class="legend">
    <div ng-repeat="item in myChartObject.data.rows">
    <div class="{{item.c[2].v}}"></div>{{item.c[0].v}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .legend{
  position:absolute;
  right:100px;
  top:30px;
}

.red{
  background:red;
  width:30px;
  height:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.green{
  background:green;
  width:30px;
  height:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**JS:** In JS add legend :none to chart options

```
$scope.myChartObject.options = {
        slices: {
            0: { color: '#50ce68' },
            1: { color: '#ff7b7b' },
        },
       legend:'none'
    };
```

updated code sample  for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qYdpaE

Comment: This is nice and upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but still there is problem of Legend.Is it possible to show legend like Success and Failed instead of values?

Comment: @User, updated my answer and codepen, legend by default uses column label , in this case "values" , one optiosn is to customize the legend

Comment: When i hover on success bar,it is showing as success/failed on bar

Comment: @User, for testing legend , i have changed label values to success/failed, I have updated codepen, hope it works now :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the data plot selecting functionality by mouse over in legend using **setSelection** method of google chart. To use this method, at first get chart instance on **agc-on-ready** directive. Then on mouse over handler of legend, call **setSelection** method of chart instance.

```
 $scope.highLight = function(arg){
     if(arg == "red"){
    ChartInstance.setSelection([{row:1,column:1}])
     }
     if(arg=="green"){
       ChartInstance.setSelection([{row:0,column:1}])
     }
   };
```

Code is given in this [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/deOpPV?editors=1010#anon-signup).